# How to resize (scale) an video using AVAssetExportSession?

Tags: avfoundation

I've looked around and can't figure this out.

I want to resize an `AVAsset` using `AVExportSession` to an given width, height.

I've looked into `AVMutableVideoComposition.renderSize` and using a scaling transform on `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` but neither of these produce expected results (stretching/cropping the final output in weird ways).

For example:

- I have a source video that is `640x320` and I want to scale it down to `320x160`.
- I set the renderSize to `CGSizeMake(320.0, 160.0)`
- I set the transform to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)`
- I get the following output where the video isn't scaled to the appropriate size (looks too big), stretched, and not centered (cropped).

[image]

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Video Resizer AVAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402633/swift-video-resizer-avasset)

Comment: Any updates about it?